# Prove that $ E \cap (F + (E \cap G)) = (E \cap F) + (E \cap G)$

Tags: vector-spaces

I have three vector subspaces of a vector space $H$ , I need to prove the following :

$$ E \cap (F + (E \cap G)) = (E \cap F) + (E \cap G)$$

I've already proved that $E + ( F \cap G) \subset  (E+F) \cap (E + G)$ , The first thing I thought of is to prove the double inclusion, i.e :

$$ E \cap (F + (E \cap G)) \subset (E \cap F) + (E \cap G)$$

and

$$ (E \cap F) + (E \cap G) \subset E \cap (F + (E \cap G)) $$

But I have no idea how to do that .

Comment: Double inclusion is exactly right. I'll start you out. Let $v\in E\cap(F+(E\cap G))$. Then $v\in E$ and $v=x+z$ for some $x\in F, z\in E\cap G$. Now examine $x$ carefully.